# Change coefficient name for stargazer output

Tags: r, regression, stargazer

I recently received a question about [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463182/how-to-output-several-variables-in-the-same-row-using-stargazer-in-r) about how to change the names of variables when outputting regression results using Stargazer. The answer didn't work for the `lrm` function from **rms**. Specifically, the coefficients were output correctly but the standard errors disappeared. Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(rms)
library(stargazer)
stargazer(attitude)

# logit models
m1 <- lrm(rating ~ complaints + learning + privileges,x=TRUE, y=TRUE,data=attitude)
m2 <- lrm(rating ~ complaints + learning + privileges,x=TRUE, y=TRUE,data=attitude)
names(m1$coefficients)[names(m1$coefficients) == "privileges"] <- "past"
names(m2$coefficients)[names(m2$coefficients) == "privileges"] <- "past"

stargazer(m1,m2, type="text")
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the `lrm` class object stores not just coefficients but the variance-covariance matrix, as well, so you need to do an additional step:

```
rownames(m1$var)[rownames(m1$var) == "privileges"] <- "past"
rownames(m2$var)[rownames(m2$var) == "privileges"] <- "past"
colnames(m1$var)[colnames(m1$var) == "privileges"] <- "past"
colnames(m2$var)[colnames(m2$var) == "privileges"] <- "past"
```

This changes the rownames and colnames of the variance-covariance matrix and thus produces the correct result:

```
stargazer(m1,m2, type="text")

==========================================
                  Dependent variable:     
              ----------------------------
                         rating           
                   (1)            (2)     
------------------------------------------

....

complaints       0.196***      0.196***   
                 (0.045)        (0.045)   

learning          0.063          0.063    
                 (0.039)        (0.039)   

past              -0.034        -0.034    
                 (0.035)        (0.035)   

------------------------------------------
Observations        30            30      
R2                0.713          0.713    
chi2 (df = 3)   37.238***      37.238***  
==========================================
Note:          *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```